# SharePoint 2007 Linked Sources and filtering

Tags: sharepoint-designer, filter, libraries

I've created a couple of linked sources before by following different tutorials and have always had pretty good luck with them.

One issue did come up and I've been stumped on it! I've joined (tried merge also) 2 different sources:

1. Item list
2. Document library

I've got one of the columns of the document library matches the column of the item list (it's actually a lookup)
I can query and filter correctly without any problem. The issue comes when I try to filter by column headers. Usually I'm able to get a dropdown with 'suggested' column filters. When you join the tables, this is no longer available and you end up having only a A-Z, Z-A sorting.

Why is this broken? Is this a SharePoint bug or simply inadequacy at doing a lookup on the dropdown?

I've managed to capture the url used in the iframe:
`_layouts/filter.aspx?ListId={YOUR-LIST-ID}&FieldInternalName=DocIcon&ViewId={YOUR-VIEW-ID}&FilterOnly=1&Filter=1`

I can't seem to capture the one that get's sent though when the datasource is a join of 2 different lists. The question is has anyone successfully enabled the column header filtering and obtained the 'suggested' filters when 2 datasources were used? If so, well how? ;)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that no answer could be found for the above. I simply went another direction by using the javascript API to get something close to what i needed.
If anyone feels like they have more to add, then please add a comment!

Thanks!

Comment: @TeckniX: Something that might help next time is if you edit your question with more info on what you've tried or perhaps some reformatting. The system will then display it on the home page of the site and catch more eyeballs.

Answer (score 0):

You may find this javascript based filtering solution to be useful

[SharePoint InstantListFilter](http://instantlistfilter.codeplex.com/)